# Openning a folder on Visual Studio Code Terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio, terminal, macos-sierra

I want to use VS Code Terminal to open a project folder in VS Code. Although I am in the **directory** that I want to open, regardless of the terminal platform(VS, Mac Terminal, or others.) I get the following error:

```
(base) Mehmet-2-MacBook-Pro:dogs-app-homework-mehmeteyupoglu Sena-2$ code .
bash: code: command not found
```

I also tried this:

```
(base) Mehmet-2-MacBook-Pro:dogs-app-homework-mehmeteyupoglu Sena-2$ code -n .
bash: code: command not found
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After a long search session, I came up with this:

Type `CMD + SHIFT + P` and choose `Shell command 'code' successfully installed in PATH.`. After this, you can use Mac's terminal to open project folders on Code.